# Adding wildcards to a workflow -- best practices

Tags: python, snakemake

I have a quite complex snakemake bioinformatics workflow consisting of >200 rules. It basically starts from a set of FASTQ files, from which variables are inferred, like so:

```
(WC1, WC2, WC3, WC4) = glob_wildcards(FASTQPATH + "{wc1}_{wc2}_{wc3}_{wc4}.fastq.gz")
```

Those are then expanded to generate the target files, for example (I am skipping intermediate rules for brevity):

```
rule all:
 expand("mappings/{wc1}_{wc2}_{wc3}_{wc4}.bam", wc1=WC1, wc2=WC2, wc3=WC3, wc4=WC4),
```

Over the course of a project, metadata can evolve and wildcards need to be added, e.g. `wc5`:

```
(WC1, WC2, WC3, WC4, WC5) = glob_wildcards(FASTQPATH + "{wc1}_{wc2}_{wc3}_{wc4}_{wc5}.fastq.gz")
```

This results in manually editing ~200 workflow rules to comply with the new input. I wonder if anyone in the community has come up with a more elegant, less cumbersome solution (using input functions perhaps?), or is it just a Snakemake limitation we all have to live with?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I have a workflow for ChIP-seq data, and my fastq files are named in the format MARK_TISSUE_REPLICATE.fastq.gz, so for example H3K4me3_Liver_B.fastq.gz. For many of my rules, I don't need to have separate wildcards for the mark, tissue, and replicate. I can just write my rules this way:

```
rule example:
    input: "{library}.fq.gz"
    output: "{library}.bam"
```

Then for the rules where I need to have multiple inputs, maybe to combine by replicates together or to do something across all tissues, I have a function I called "libraries" that returns a list of libraries with certain criteria. For example libraries(mark="H3K4me3") would return all libraries for that mark, or libraries(tissue="Liver", replicate="A") would return the libraries for all marks from that specific tissue sample. I can use this to write rules that need to combine multiple libraries, such as:

```
rule example2:
    input: lambda wildcards: expand("{library}.bam", library=libraries(mark=wildcards.mark))
    output: "{mark}_Heatmap_Clustering.png"
```

To fix some weird or ambiguous rule problems, I found it helpful to set some wildcard constraints like this:

```
wildcard_constraints:
    mark="[^_/]+",
    tissue="[^_/]+",
    replicate="[^_/]+",
    library="[^_/]+_[^_/]+_[^_/]+"
```

Hopefully you can apply some of these ideas to your own workflow.

Answer (score 1):

I think @Colin is on the right (most snakemake-ish) path here. However if you want to make use of the wildcards, e.g. in the log or they dictate certain parameters then you could try to replace the wildcards by a variable, and inject this in the input and output of rules:

```
metadata = "{wc1}_{wc2}_{wc3}_{wc4}"
WC1, WC2, WC3, WC4 = glob_wildcards(FASTQPATH + metadata + ".fastq.gz") 

rule map:
    input:
        expand(f"unmapped/{metadata}.fq")
    input:
        expand(f"mappings/{metadata}.fq")
    shell:
        """
        echo {wildcards.wc1};
        mv {input} {output}
        """

rule all:
    expand("mappings/{wc1}_{wc2}_{wc3}_{wc4}.bam", wc1=WC1, wc2=WC2, wc3=WC3, wc4=WC4)
```

This way changing to more or less wildcards is relatively easy.

**disclaimer** I haven't tested whether any of this actually works :)